# How do I return only the most recent record based on Date

Tags: sql-server, date

I need to get my query to return only the most recent record based on Employee Starting Date.  I think I need a max date inner join but I can't get it to work.  Does anyone have any advice for me?  I'm using TOAD for SQL Developer.

```
SELECT
  e.No_,
  ep.[Classification Description],
  ep.[Employee Starting Date],
  ep.[Standard Rate],
  ep.[Over Award Rate],
  ep.[Employee Rate],
  p.[Job Title],
  e.[First Name],
  e.[Last Name],
  e.[Payroll No_]
FROM Employee e,
     [Payroll Employee] p,
     [Employee Pay Rate] ep
WHERE e.No_ = p.[Employee No_]
AND e.No_ = ep.[Employee No_]
AND ep.[Employee No_] = p.[Employee No_]
AND e.[Payroll No_] = 'PAY7'
AND CAST(e.[Termination Date] AS date) = '1753-01-01'
```

Comment: Do you want every employees most recent record or do you just want the most recent record? and which date? `Employee Starting Date`?

Comment: Add schema sample data and desired output

Comment: additional question.. is this real? "'1753-01-01'"

Comment: If it is SQL Server try doing explicit JOINs instead of cross join like this FROM Employee e,
     [Payroll Employee] p,
     [Employee Pay Rate] ep

Comment: 1753-01-01 is the minvalue for a date. Why would you use this? You should use NULL for non terminated employees

Answer (score 0):

You can do group by and get min or max date accordingly as below:

```
SELECT
  e.No_,
  ep.[Classification Description],
  MAX(ep.[Employee Starting Date]) as [Employee Starting Date], --hope it is min based on your logic
  ep.[Standard Rate],
  ep.[Over Award Rate],
  ep.[Employee Rate],
  p.[Job Title],
  e.[First Name],
  e.[Last Name],
  e.[Payroll No_]
FROM Employee e
    INNER JOIN [Payroll Employee] p
    ON e.No_ = p.[Employee No_]
    INNER JOIN [Employee Pay Rate] ep
    ON e.No_ = ep.[Employee No_]
    AND ep.[Employee No_] = p.[Employee No_]
WHERE 
    e.[Payroll No_] = 'PAY7'
AND CAST(e.[Termination Date] AS date) = '1753-01-01'
GROUP BY 
  e.No_,
  ep.[Classification Description],
  ep.[Standard Rate],
  ep.[Over Award Rate],
  ep.[Employee Rate],
  p.[Job Title],
  e.[First Name],
  e.[Last Name],
  e.[Payroll No_]
```